# Viewing the contents of a JAR file

Tags: java, jar, corda

I can't seem to view the contents of a JAR file, I tried it using various decompilers, but doesn't seem to work on a particular file, any ideas?
I even tried unzipping it. Both these solutions are working for most JAR files but not all.

https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-releases/net/corda/corda/2.0.0/

I want to view the corda-2.0.0.jar file.

Comment: Unzipping should work 100% of the time. If it doesn't, the jar file is not valid or correct. That has nothing to do with decompilation.

Comment: Define "nott working".

Comment: This is strange: it's a jar of jars

Comment: How were you even able to see that? I was just shown that archive cant be opened.

Answer (score 0):

`jar tf corda-2.0.0.jar` lists contents of `corda-2.0.0.jar` just fine.

Surprizingly, `jar xf corda-2.0.0.jar` does not extract the files. No output, no errors, no files extracted.

Simple `unzip corda-2.0.0.jar` worked fine and extracted all the contents.

Comment: It's an "uber" jar or "fat" jar.  Maybe `xf` doesn't work with fatjar?

Answer (score 0):

I am using 7-zip to extract files and view